# when dynamically added form field not getting value from post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I am calling a file `getattributes.php` using `ajax` and from that file I am appending a table which contains some checkboxes.It is appending successfully but the problem is when I am submitting the form I am not getting the value of those fields which is added dynamically.I also know that there is similar question in stackoverflow but still I am having problem.

getattributes.php  :-

```
    <tr><th><?php echo($exquery['specification_name']);?></th>

    <?php $getattribute = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE specification_id = '".$specifi_id[$i]."'  ";
    $executeattribute = mysql_query($getattribute);

    while($attibutes = mysql_fetch_assoc($executeattribute))
    {
        $attributecount = $attributecount + 1;
    ?>

        <td><input type='checkbox' value='<?php echo($attibutes['attribute_id']);?>' name='attribute_id<?php echo($i);?>[]'>&nbsp;<?php echo($attibutes['attribute_name']);?></td>
        <input type='hidden' name = 'attribute_id<?php echo($i);?>[]' value='<?php echo($attibutes['attribute_id']);?>' id='spec<?php echo $i;?>attr<?php echo $attributecount?>'/>
    <?php }?>

    </tr>
    <?php
        $attributecount = 0;
    ?>
    <!--<input type='hidden' name = 'test' value='<?php echo $attributecount;?>' id='spec<?php echo $i;?>'/>-->

<?php }
```

I am also adding snapshot which shows that it is successfully appending on my form :-

[image]

Here specification table is added dynamically and I want to get the value of brand and color checkboxes.I dont know what is the problem.

EDIT :- post method code

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="myform">
  // some field //


</form>
```

and I am checking post value using `print_r($_POST)` and I am getting all the value of form but not getting the field value which is added dynamically

Thanks in advance

Comment: you'll need to post some of the code that handles the POST

Comment: values from checkboxes are only shown when the checkbox has been checked prior to submitting

Comment: I am checking post value after selecting checkbox

Comment: how are you checking the values then? just printing the $_POST var doesn't do much for unchecked radiobuttons...

Comment: @Reinder I didnt get any answer so why should I accept your answer.The problem was in the from element i.e, one div tag was creating this problem.So I solved it.Also Dude what you provide as as answer-I already told you that I was checking my post value after selecting a checkbox.

Comment: you've only said you're using print_r($_POST) to check for the values, but as I already stated in my answer, that will only show you which checkboxes have been checked.

Comment: So, was my answers helpfull? Did you manage to solve this issue? Please update this SO item...

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($_POST)` will only show a checkbox value if that particular checkbox was checked when submitting the form

to check if a checkbox has been checked, use this:

```
if( isset($_POST["Name-Of-Checkbox"]) ) {
    $checkboxIsChecked = true;
}
```

Comment: I am checking post value after selecting checkbox